# Need to find the lowest nodes in a tree

Tags: algorithm, tree

I have a list of nodes that are part of a tree. I want to filter the list to only the lowest children. For an example tree:

```
(1)
 |
 +-- (2)
 |    
 +-- (3)
    |
    +-- (4)
    |  
    +-- (5)
         |
         +--(6)
```

If my list is `[1,2,5,6]`, I would want the results to be `[2,6]` because they are the lowest descendants.

I have a node method `is_descendant()` that takes two nodes, and returns `True` or `False`.

For example:

```
1.is_descendant(2) ---> False
2.is_descendant(1) ---> True
6.is_descendant(1) ---> True
```

My first idea is to start with the first element in the list and apply the `is_descendant()` method to every other element. Whenever it returns `True`, I would remove the other item from the list - since it is a parent node.

Is there a more efficient way to do this? Or will this method work 100% of the time (proof possible?)

Comment: By 'lowest descendants' do you mean the nodes at the deepest level *for each child of `(1)`*?

Comment: Not necessarily, because in this structure nodes can have multiple parents and multiple children. I need a list where no node in the list is an ancestor of any other node in that list.

Comment: If the nodes have child pointers, it's easy - just list the ones where the child pointers are NULL.

Comment: @Internal Server Error I still want nodes with descendants, just as long as none of those descendants are in the list

Comment: @max You really need to do some more work on your example.  There are no nodes with multiple parents in the example. And nodes 2 and 6 don't have any children. So the example isn't really representative of the problem you are describing here in the comments.

Comment: Why `[2,6]` instead of `[6]`? The deepest node for `1` is `6`. If you don't think so, then why do you consider `6` for parent `3` and not consider `4` for parent `3`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rule appears to be, if a node is in the list, and any of its descendants are in the list, then the node should be removed from the list. This can be implemented using a fairly simple recursive function.

Some Java code to ilustrate:

```
static <E> boolean descendentsIn(Node<E> node, Set<E> nodes)
{
  boolean descendentsIn = false;
  for(Node<E> n : node.children)
  {
    if(descendentsIn(n, nodes) || nodes.contains(n.e)) 
      descendentsIn = true;
  }
  if(descendentsIn && nodes.contains(node.e)) 
    nodes.remove(node.e);
  return descendentsIn;
}

static class Node<E>
{
  E e;
  List<Node<E>> children = new ArrayList<>();
  public Node(E e)
  {
    this.e = e;
  }
}
```

Test:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
  Node<Integer> root = new Node<>(1);
  root.children.add(new Node<>(2));
  root.children.add(new Node<>(3));
  root.children.get(1).children.add(new Node<>(4));
  root.children.get(1).children.add(new Node<>(5));
  root.children.get(1).children.get(1).children.add(new Node<>(6));

  Set<Integer> nodes = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 5, 6));

  System.out.println("Before: " + nodes);
  descendentsIn(root, nodes);    
  System.out.println("After:  " + nodes);
}
```

Output:

```
Before: [1, 2, 5, 6]
After:  [2, 6]
```